# imageButton in android's dialog?

Tags: java, android, layout, dialog, imagebutton

I want to put an imageButton instead of the default positive button.
using layout is not good enough because it doesn't replace the positive button.
does anyone know if it is possible to override the default buttons, or set their background?

Comment: This is not good information,review your question and gives perfect and full detailed question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about creating an AlertDialog. Why not just create your own custom dialog? You can specify your `ImageButton` in a layout, then create a dialog with that layout, you don't need to go near the positive button.

More info here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog